# how to start oracle instance. forgot uname pwd

Tags: oracle, ora-01034

this one isn't a dev question but silly tech quesiton...

I had installed oracle 10g on my local windows box.  When I open the Database Control window in IE it shows that listener is up but instance is down. I try to start it from there but it says wrong uname pwd.  How can I start the instance or find my uname and pwd?

Error:

```
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in as a member of the ORA_DBA group, open a command window, set your ORACLE_SID to the name of your instance, and enter:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup
```

At that point, change the password for the user you've forgotten the PW for.

Comment: I tried this and updated the question with the error that I get

Comment: Are there any interesting messages in the alert log file?

Comment: had to restart the service. that fixed it